# How to Make Auto Size Horizontal Line DIV using css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slick.js

I have *Hour to Hour* Horizontal line (also use [slick jQuery plugin](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick)) that created using multiple  element like below image :

[image]

Unfortunately, everytime i do zoom out, the line **cannot auto size** and **can not be** **responsive** but being broken. I have tried changing attribute of `line-0` `width:100%` or auto and add `overflow:hidden;` but it does not work.

[image]

The HTML:

```
<div class="hour">
    <div id="1" class='fl'>
            <div id="this_hour" class='fl kurohige-prev jaman' data-time="11">00:00-01:00</div>
            <div class='fl line-0'></div>                   
    </div>
    <div id="2" class='fl'>
            <div id="this_hour" class='fl kurohige-prev jaman' data-time="11">01:00-02:00</div>
            <div class='fl line-0'></div>                   
    </div>
    <div id="3" class='fl'>
            <div id="this_hour" class='fl kurohige-prev jaman' data-time="11">02:00-03:00</div>
            <div class='fl line-0'></div>                   
    </div>  
    <div id="4" class='fl'>
            <div id="this_hour" class='fl kurohige-prev jaman' data-time="11">03:00-04:00</div>
            <div class='fl line-0'></div>                   
    </div>  
</div>
```

The CSS :

```
.kurohige {
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: "am";
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 7px 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

.fl {
    float: left;
}

.line-0 {
    background: #ffffff none repeat scroll 0 0;
    height: 2px;
    margin: 18px 0; 
    width: 100px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Does anybody have any suggestion or solution for this ? 
Do i need to use **bootstrap** to fix this ?

thanks before...

Comment: Hey @user2226388, which browsers do you need to support?

Comment: @jh3y, i'm using Chrome...

Comment: Why don't you use a single infinite line made of an image background (repeat-x)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you liked and your browser support allowed it, you could use a `flexbox` solution for your needs (you can check out a nice `flexbox` reference over @ css-tricks.com [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)).

**EDITED::**

I've put together the following snippet which can also be seen on jsbin [here](http://jsbin.com/jeqihorire/edit?html,css,output).

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.times {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #f00;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  list-style: none;
}
.times__time {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  min-width: 20%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.times__time:before,
.times__time:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -0.5px;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
.times__time:before {
  left: 0;
  right: 50%;
  /* This must be half of the size of the label*/
  margin-right: 12.5px;
}
.times__time:after {
  right: 0;
  left: 50%;
  /* This must be half of the size of the label*/
  margin-left: 12.5px;
}

.times__time:first-of-type:before,
.times__time:last-of-type:after {
  border: none;
}

.time__time-label {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 100%;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <div class="times">
    <div class="times__time">
      <div class="time__time-label">A</div>
    </div>
    <div class="times__time">
      <div class="time__time-label">B</div>
    </div>
    <div class="times__time">
      <div class="time__time-label">C</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

If you resize the output, the lines will extend between items. I'm hoping this is the behaviour you desire.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi @jh3y, how to change <nav> <li> to <div> <div> ? is it possible? Because i want to use [slick slider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) that need nested <div>...

Comment: Hi @jh3y, i have modified it using div, however the span (line) streak div because it's transparent. as seen in http://prntscr.com/8bni6j ,how to fix this ?

Comment: I've updated the snippet and jsbin link in my answer to use CSS pseudo elements. This should help you out and get the desired behaviour. Please mark as accepted if this fixes it for you. Hope it helps :D